# let $a^2 >4bc $ such that $a,b ,c \neq 0$ then find $a , b , c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> let $a^2 >4bc , b^2>4ac ,c^2 > 4ab $ such that $a,b ,c \neq 0$ then find range of $a , b , c$

in fact I want that $ax^2+bx+c =0 , bx^2+ax+c=0,cx^2+ax+b=0$ have Two distinct roots
.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel. my try : $a^2+b^2+c^2 > 4(ab+ac+bc ) $ but I don't know!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a,b,c$ are all positive or all negative, then $a^2b^2c^2>64a^2b^2c^2$ which is impossible.

Without loss of generality suppose that two of the variables, $b$ and $c$ say, have the same sign. Then we simply require $|a|>2\sqrt {bc}$ with $a$ having the opposite sign to $b$ and $c$..

Comment: why when $b,c$ have the same sigh then we must have $a^2 > 4bc $

Comment: Because $bc$ is then positive.

Comment: When b and c have the same sign and a has a different sign the quantities 4ab and 4ac are both negative and are therefore automatically less than any non-zero square.